# Как вывести в одном блоке несколько циклов v-for

Tags: vue.js

Подскажите как решить задачу - данные с сервера приходят динамически и складываются в массивы. Нужно в одной карточке (одном блоке) вывести все эти данные по очереди, то есть создать список из нескольких карточек).

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    object: [{
        names: [1, 2, 3, 4]
      },
      {
        dates: ['25/12/2006', '25/12/2007', '25/12/20011',
          '25/12/2006'
        ]
      },
      {
        hours: [6, 3, 4, 5]
      },
      {
        people: [10, 11, 3, 5]
      }
    ]
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>List of orders</h2>
  <div class="card">
    <ol>
      <li v-for="item in object">
        {{item.names}} {{item.dates}} {{item.hours}} {{item.people}}
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пример тут https://jsfiddle.net/igorlocal/2uzp9gyq/14/

Comment: Добрый день. Можно сделать активной и здесь, а что именно не получается? вы хотите чтобы он брал по интексу данные?

Comment: Мне нужно на каждой карточке выводить по одному элементу - то есть делать перебор приходящих с сервера данных, чтобы получилась вот такая картинка:

Карточка 1
--------------
1
25/12/2006
6
10

Карточка 2
--------------
2
25/12/2007
3
11

и тд

То есть по очереди выводить по одному экзмемпляра данных из вложенных массивов на карточку

Answer (score 0):

Я бы изменил данные с сервера, но вот вариант решения вашей задачи, либо нужно организовать новый массив.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    object: [{
        names: [1, 2, 3, 4]
      },
      {
        dates: ['25/12/2006', '25/12/2007', '25/12/20011',
          '25/12/2006'
        ]
      },
      {
        hours: [6, 3, 4, 5]
      },
      {
        people: [10, 11, 3, 5]
      }
    ]
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>List of orders</h2>
  <div class="card" v-for="(item, index) in object[0].names" :key="index">
    {{ index }} --- {{ object[0].names[index] }} | {{ object[1].dates[index] }} | {{ object[2].hours[index] }} | {{ object[3].people[index] }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите как лучше оптимизировать данные с сервера?

Comment: Дело в том, что ваш вариант решения выводит все данные на одну карточку. А мне нужно другое решение - одна карточка содержит только по одному элементу names, dates, hours, people

Comment: ну так нужно v-for на карточке сделать, сейчас

Comment: По данным с сервера если вы не можете повлиять на то что отдает сервер то перебирать их и создавать новый массив, если можете повлиять то организовать вывод одним массивом.

Comment: Да, спасибо - буду вот этот сценарий прорабатывать: создавать новый массив из того, что получаю с сервера

Answer (score 0):

После изменения данных, приходящих с сервера, мой код выглядит следующим образом.
Вопрос - данные приходят с сервера динамически в виде массива объектов
objects: [
         { name: 1, code: 9623, object: '019 СМР ОПС', date:                  '25/12/2006', hour: 3, people: 1
         },
         { 
           name: 2, code: 9623, object: '019 СМР ОПС', date:                  '15/10/2006', hour: 1, people: 4
         },
         { name: 3, code: 9623, object: '019 СМР ОПС', date:                  '05/11/2008', hour: 2, people: 3},
         { name: 4, code: 9623, object: '019 СМР ОПС', date:                 '01/03/2004', hour: 10, people: 6},
      ],

Как добавить эти данные в data, для корректного отображения в шаблоне?

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    objects: [
         { name: 1, code: 9623, object: '019 СМР ОПС', date:                  '25/12/2006', hour: 3, people: 1
         },
         { 
           name: 2, code: 9623, object: '019 СМР ОПС', date:                  '15/10/2006', hour: 1, people: 4
         },
         { name: 3, code: 9623, object: '019 СМР ОПС', date:                  '05/11/2008', hour: 2, people: 3},
         { name: 4, code: 9623, object: '019 СМР ОПС', date:                 '01/03/2004', hour: 10, people: 6},
      ],
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h2>List of orders</h2>
  <div class="card" v-for="(item, index) in objects" :key="index">
    {{ index }} --- {{ item.names }} | {{ item.date }} | {{ item.object }} | {{ item.people }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вам нужно создать второй вопрос, не продолжая этот. Данный вопрос не пройдет проверку и будет удален. А в кранце пуште свой массив новыми данными и они будут отображены.